# sed: stripping quotes from around numbers

Tags: bash, sed

I am parsing a CSV file that looks like this :

```
999,"FOO",0.00249,0.00249,0.00249,0.0000,1,1
888,"BAR",0.00249,0.00249,0.00249,0.0000,1,1
777,"FOOBAR",0.00999,0.00999,0.00999,0.0000,1,1
666,"ABC",0.00999,0.00999,0.00999,0.0000,1,1
555,"DEF","-0.00100","-0.00100","-0.00100",0.0000,1,1
444,"EFG","-0.00100","-0.00100","-0.00100",0.0000,1,1
```

The only column that should be quote-delimited is the second colum (e.g. `"FOO"`,`"BAR"` etc.).  The other columns are always to be interpreted as numeric.

As you can see in the above example, lines 555 and 444 have a quoted numeric value `"-0.00100"`.

I am therefore looking to strip quotes from around numeric values.

I have done a little research on here on Stackoverflow and identified the following:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18624948/4474629

I have tried to adapt it thus :

`column -t -s,  | sed s/"(-?\d[\d.]*)"/\1/g | more`

But the output still prints ?

```
555      "DEF"               "-0.00100"  "-0.00100"  "-0.00100"  0.0000  1   1
444       "EFG"               "-0.00100"  "-0.00100"  "-0.00100"  0.0000  1   1
```

The expected result is:

```
555      "DEF"               -0.00100  -0.00100  -0.00100  0.0000  1   1
444       "EFG"               -0.00100  -0.00100  -0.00100  0.0000  1   1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at [the sed manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#BRE-syntax), you will see that neither `(` nor `?` nor `\d` nor `)` are supported. The question you linked to used perl, where these constructs work.

You can adapt your script thus:

```
sed 's/"\(-\?[0-9][0-9.]*\)"/\1/g'
```

(using single quotes to prevent interpretation of special characters by the shell).

Even `\?` is a GNU extension; if your sed doesn't support it, you may have to use `-\{0,1\}` instead.

Comment: Any particular reason for `[0-9.]` instead of `[.][0-9]`?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Well, it's what OP had. If I wanted to allow an arbitrary number of digits with at most one `.`, I'd use something like `[0-9]\+\(\.[0-9]\+\)\?`.

Comment: Yep, that'd work too and allow for zero padded decimals.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/"//3g' file
```

Only the second column is quoted therefore there should only be 2 double quotes and any others should be removed.